# OSError while reading the project from Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, project, oserror

OSError Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment

This was the error I'm getting when i tried to compare the files from oracle to Google cloud (screenshot of result console)

[image: 1]

platform.please help me with this.

Comment: Edit your question and provide more details. What commands are you running?

Comment: I have attached screenshot of result console, please check it once. Is that doesn't work i can add more

Comment: Please put everything in your question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @SatishDandangi Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing a [similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74866327/oserror-whilst-trying-to-run-a-python-app-inside-a-docker-container-using-appl).

Answer (score 0):

After downloading gcloud CLI and run  `gcloud auth application-default login` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc)) , I ran this code and it works fine. Where all the arguments are `str`.

```
def upload_blob(project_name, bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):

    storage_client = storage.Client(project=project_name)
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```